# Messages printed in Log-cat while using Smart Reply

Tags: firebase-mlkit

In the Fire base ML Kit, the message list given for suggesting reply is being printed in the logcat

Just call FirebaseNaturalLanguage.getInstance().getSmartReply().suggestReplies(List samplelist) , the messages sent in the samplelist being printed in Logcat

ArrayList messageList = new ArrayList<>();
messageList.add(new Message("Hello. How are you?", false, System.currentTimeMillis()));

List chatHistory = new ArrayList<>();
      for (Message message : messageList) {
          if (message.isLocalUser && !isEmulatingRemoteUser || !message.isLocalUser && isEmulatingRemoteUser) {
              chatHistory.add(FirebaseTextMessage.createForLocalUser(message.text,
                      message.timestamp));
          } else {
              chatHistory.add(FirebaseTextMessage.createForRemoteUser(message.text,
                      message.timestamp, REMOTE_USER_ID));
          }
      }
     FirebaseNaturalLanguage.getInstance().getSmartReply().suggestReplies(chatHistory)
              .continueWith(new Continuation>() {
                  @Override
                  public List then(@NonNull Task task) {
                      return task.getResult().getSuggestions();
                  }
              });

Observed Results:
In the logcat, the message list given is being printed in logcat.
Expected Results:
Message list given should not be printed in logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update both `com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-natural-language` and `com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-natural-language-smart-reply-model`
to `20.0.2`

Comment: This worked for me, and should be marked as the answer! Thank you!